# DPDK testpmd shows link down even though it is up

Tags: dpdk

I've been trying to use DPDK's NFP poll mode driver inside a docker image to bind a Netronome NIC, however when running testpmd the link is always shown as "down" even though it is up (it has been tested in other ways).

The NIC is visible under Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver when running 
dpdk-devbind.py --status after running the following commands:

modprobe vfio-pci
dpdk-devbind.py --bind=vfio-pci 5e:00.0

However when running the following, it is still shown as down in testpmd.

./app/dpdk-testpmd -- -i
set link-up port 0
show port info 0

Any ideas?

Comment: @LinaBolmkvist can you please share the following information, DPDK version, NFP NIC, firmware, Driver details, is this PF|VF|PF-multiport? Can you also please share the result of running the same interface on HOST (no docker)? Can you share the result of testpmd without forcing link-up too? Note: due to missing details marking as need more information.

Comment: are there any updates?

Comment: please update your dpdk logs with `--log-level=pmd,8`, Netronome NIC details, dpdk version. In my last debug with the network vendor we found NIC, firmware, dpdk matters. Assuming it is dpdk 20.11.1 LTS the firmware required is `1.10.1.70`.

Comment: I had raised the missing details, But looks like `it was marked invalidate because someone felt this can easily be debugged without any information (dpdk, nic, firmware)`. I humbly request to people who review to please diligently review the reason why it had been marked insufficient information before marking invalid.

Comment: are there any updates from your end?

Answer (score 0):

As per DPDK documentation, NFP PMD supports

1. PF
2. PF multiport
3. SRIOV VF NIC

In the all above cases Board Support Package has to loaded and initialized with the right firmware ([More details from DPDK documentation](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/nfp.html). There is special case `The PMD PF has extra work to do which will delay the DPDK app initialization like uploading the firmware and configure the Link state properly when starting or stopping a PF port. Since DPDK 18.05 the firmware upload happens when a PF is initialized, which was not always true with older DPDK versions.`

Note: In comments sample code (or snippet), DPDK version and NIC firmware are requested.

Hence as suggested by NFP PMD maintainers please factor in the necessary delay to get the link-state up.